# @model doesn't exist in my view with VS2015 but work fine with VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I've a project created with Visual Studio 2012 and it work fine, but when i open it with Visual Studio 2015 Entreprise Edition, i don't why but in my all views @model, ViewBag & co, doesn't exist VS2015 say "The 'model' doesn't exist in the current context" BUT my project compil WELL and work.

[print screen here, on the left side from VS2012 on the right side from VS2015, the same view in the same project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u68sl.png)

Did someone already had that problem ?

My project is an basic ASP.NET MVC3 Project With RazorViewEngine

Comment: Do you have resharper installed and enabled? If so, try disabling/suspending it?

Comment: Did you update VS 2015 Update 1 please update your visual studio than try again :)

Comment: No i've not Resharper

Comment: Yes 2015 is up to date.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Comment: Check the web.config for your views and update and check the settings there if its compatible with vs 15

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the @Html, @Html.Label, @Html.Hidden and the basic work in VS2015.